# Initial condition distributions for phase space densities

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I'm having difficulty understanding Liouville's theorem: I have seen the quantity $\rho(p,q;t)$ defined (i) using ensemble theory as the probability density function over realizations/copies of an orbit in phase space and described (ii) as the density of neighboring orbits in phase space corresponding to many particles.  I don't understand description (ii); if, for example, orbits are calculated using Hamilton's equations, shouldn't each particle evolve along a collection of trajectories defined using various initial data?  How can we construct a density in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first note that $p,q$ here are not coordinates of a single particle, but of all the particles in the system, and a point in a phase space is a state of the system.

Now,an important assumption in statistical physics is *ergodicity* - that is that the averaging over time can he replaced by an ensemble averaging. In other words, instead of observing a long trajectory of a single system, we can consider trajectories of many systems with different initial conditions. This also implies that the trajectory of the single system would be ling enough to visit all the accessible points in the phase space.

Comment: Hi Roger, thanks for your answer!  This clears it up; what I had not realized was that the density functions $\rho(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p};\,t)$ of statistical ensembles are *defined* as continuous functions that correspond to collections of $N$ pairs $(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})$ all evolving under Hamilton's equations with the same Hamiltonian that produce the same particular macro-state at time $t$ in the limit $N \rightarrow \infty$ (a "point cloud" in phase space,) and that such a collection can be viewed as just a collection of initial conditions!

Comment: I do not understand how the ergodic hypothesis comes into play here; how can that connection between ensemble averages and time averages help to understand the interpretation of the density function?